# Vuejs frontend served by Express and backend API in node security practice

Tags: node.js, security, express, ssl, heroku

I am currently working on a small project where I used `vue.js` to build the front end and `express.js` for the backend.

For the frontend, I have another `express` server to just serve the static files and all the requests will be redirected to my backend API with proxy by the frontend server.

For the backend, it is just an Express API app.

Both apps are runing on heroku right now. And my questions is:

1. What is the best practice to connect the front end and back end server, I did a lot of research online and people are saying backend API are not supposed to be exposed to internet？ I am not sure how I can talk to my backend if it is not on internet.
2. For the frontend, I can use SSL/TLS to protect the connection. But for frontend to backend server communication, what should I do to protect this data transfer, can I use another SSL/TLS? And should I use some mechanism to verify that the request is sent from my frontend server, not somewhere else? If so, what is the recommanded way to do that?
3. A lot people say that there should not be direct connection with database, it should go through a web service for security. What does that means? Now in my backend Express app, I have line of `mongoose.connect('mongodb://someaddress/myapp');` Is this bad practice? If so, what should I do to make it more secure?

Please try to be more specific, I am still new to theses and try to learn, code examples can really help. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Vue and Express apps are written in the same language, so it is best practice to have these as separate projects as you have done. These are entirely different projects doing different things so they should be split.
2. You already deployed to Heroku, so the SSL/TLS isn't really a concern for you. However if you were deploying to your own VPS, you'd want something like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). For restricting requests from Express to your Vue app, you'll want to look into [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). See [expressjs/cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) for more details.
3. The Express app *is* the service connecting to your database. If you were trying to directly connect to your database from your Vue app, then that becomes an issue. You would coupling client side code with server side code. What you're doing is fine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the response, but I still have a question regarding the SSL. Even thought my frontend is hosted at heroku, when I do a post request, I can still see plain text through the network tab. So I was wondering if I need to add anything in front end for it to be encrypted?

Comment: Yes you can. [The same thing happens when you login to facebook](https://i.imgur.com/WhLJA1R.png). The SSL/TLS part is to ensure your network traffic is secure en route to its destination which is your Express app. See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) answer for more details